# what does PHP.getimagesize actually return

Tags: php, image, getimagesize

The PHP manual says that it returns up to 7 elements.  and says 0, 1 are width and height followed by image type and attribute.  Then it goes on to give the an example so

```
$size=getimagesize()
```

So, what does it return ?  An array of 7 elements or just one ?  Or is it auto-magical ?  Actually I want the width, height, type and size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll get image `height`, `width` and `type` from `getimagesize()` but for size, you can use `filesize()` function. Please check below example -

```
//Get image information
$getImageInfo = getimagesize("123.png");
print_r($getImageInfo);
//Get image size information
echo filesize("123.png");
```

### Output

Array
(
    [0] => 657
    [1] => 543
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="657" height="543"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
254387

Please make it correct answer, if this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$info   = getimagesize("path/to/image");
$mime   = $info['mime']; 
$width  = $info[0];
$height = $info[1];
$type   = $info[2];
$size = $info[3];
```

Comment: I know how to use the   list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize.  My question is, is it returning the filesize or the list of elements.

Comment: Does it return the filesize or does it return an array of values (where none are the filesize) ?

Comment: @youssif Index 3 is not file size as in bytes but rather a string that can be used in an IMG tag.

Answer (score 2):

var_dump(getimagesize('path/to/some/image.ext');

This would have answered your question and returned something like:

```
array(7) { [0]=> int(2048) 
           [1]=> int(852) 
           [2]=> int(2) 
           [3]=> string(25) "width="2048" height="852"" 
           ["bits"]=> int(8) 
           ["channels"]=> int(3) 
           ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" }
```

Note that index 2 is a constant of type IMAGETYPE_XXX. File size is not returned by this function. For our case this will give you the width and height. You can use filesize() to get the size of the file.

Comment: Ok, I see my confusion stems from most of the examples   $size=getimagesize().  And the discussion I have encountered indicates that it is the size of the image.  I assumed it was filesize, but I guess it returns the width in this case.  Thanks

Comment: @RohitGupta Your expectations should have been correct. It is not a very clear function name as size usually refers to the disk space required to store some piece of information. PHP is full of awkwardly named functions. It probably should have been named getImageDimensionsAndOtherThingsToo()